# Link should navigate for book after a certion time

Tags: asp.net

I have a aspx page for booking tickets,  and i am providing link to users  through mail(link of booking page) .
when they click that link it should check the time 09:00 AM then it should navigate to booking page else redirect to another page showing message **"not allowed this time"**

Comment: If it is aspx page, then in Page_Load method check if current time is > 9.00 a.m. then navigate to your required page, else add your error message. It would be better if you can add some code here to understand the problem better

Comment: What did you try? What is your exact problem? Redirecting? Checking current time? Doing it all when loading a page?

Comment: if (System.DateTime.Now.Hour <= 9)
                {
                   //should show "not allowed this time"   
                }  // what about 2 PM  it will convert internally to 14 or it will consider as 2 and show "not allowed this time"

Answer (score 0):

```
if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 9)
    Response.Redirect("Page.aspx");
else
    Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Not allowed this time');</script>");
```

You are checking for a Current time of the Server using `DateTime.Now.Hour`. It takes current time from a server, and taking only HOUR part of this datetime. If your hour is 9 o'clock (it don't consider minutes), user will be redirected to the some `Page.aspx`. You have to change the name.
If it is not 9 o'clock, corresponding alert will be displayed.

Comment: also you have to consider, that DateTime.Now.Hour takes the time from your server, not client.

Comment: Please explain your answer.